# Detect bot on AWS

Tags: aws, load-balancing

We use angular for our front end, our compiled dist folder is uploaded to an S3 bucket which is connected to a load balancer. In order for our site to be rendered correctly for search engine bots we implemented Angular Universal which is running on an ec2-instance. The question is among all AWS service which one can we use to detect bot(or even allow a script that does) and redirect to the ec2-instance. Or is there any alternative approach this can take?
I am currently looking into cloudfront and lamba.

Comment: It is not different content, bot can't crawl pure angular code, this is not cheating it is done by all this situation.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to segregate users by JavaScript support.

Looking at duckduckgo.com?q=example one can observe the following;

```
<noscript>
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=/html?q=example">
</noscript>
```

Checking the user agent is another solution ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20084513/detect-search-crawlers-via-javascript)).